How to save blob file into a data base?
i have a python code that i want to use file dialog to grab an image file from the PC files and save to thee MySQL database
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pymysql


    def connectDB():
        global mycursor, con
        try:
            con=pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='password', db='dbname')
            mycursor=con.cursor()
            messagebox.showinfo('Success!', 'Connected')
        except:
            messagebox.showerror('Error!', 'Unable To Connect  To server')


    def savedata():
        fn = filedialog.askopenfile(title='Select File', filetypes=(('Image File', '*.jpg'), ('All
     Files', '*.*')))
        with open(fn, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read()
        query = 'INSERT INTO files(id, file_data, date) VALUES(NULL, %s, NOW())'
        mycursor.execute(query, (data,))
        con.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo('success', 'succesfuly saved')
    
    win =Tk()
    Button(win, text='save data to DB', command=savedata).pack()
    win.mainloop()

and this is the output
C:\Users\Lael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe C:\Users\Lael\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\prac.py 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lael\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\prac.py", line 22, in savedata
    fn = filedialog.askopenfile(title='Select File', filetypes=(('Image File', '*.jpg'), ('All Files', '*.*')))
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 410, in askopenfile
    return open(filename, mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Lael/Downloads/lele.jpg'

